# Using [[deprecated]] attribute when warnings are errors (-Werror)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, c++14, compiler-warnings

I'm migrating to C++14 and keen to adopt its `[[deprecated]]` functionality, e.g.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

[[deprecated]]
int f() { return 42; }

int main()
{
  std::cout << f() << std::endl;
}
```

compiled with

```
g++ example.cpp -std=c++14 -Werror
```

and the problem is the deprecated warning is promoted (demoted?) to an error and the build fails.

Obviously using a `#pragma` to silence the warning completely defeats the point. Is there any way to tell g++ to emit warnings yet exclude specific ones from being treated as errors?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to add

```
-Wno-error=deprecated-declarations
```

to tell gcc to keep `deprecated-declarations` as a warning instead of making it an error.

You can add additional

```
-Wno-error=name_of_warning
```

if you have additional warnings that you would like to not be treated as errors as well.

Answer (score 5):

With GCC (And also Clang) you can disable errors for specific warnings.

Using `-Wno-error=` followed by the name of the warning (displayed together with the warning or error) will disable the error for that specific item.

For your case with `[[deprecated]]`, use the option `-Wno-error=deprecated-declaration`, and those will become warnings again instead of errors.

Comment: I get `g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Werror-no-deprecated-declarations’; did you mean ‘--warn-no-deprecated-declarations`. The one it suggests silences the waring completely

Comment: @virgesmith Oops, slight typo... Fixed :)